# What is the type of the function g = (.).(.)?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, currying, parametric-polymorphism

The answer is: `(a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b`

But I don't know how to get there.

Comment: Write the type of `(.)` as `A -> B` for some A and B. Then write the type of the second `(.)` as `C -> D` -- it will be the same as `A -> B`, but using distinct type variables. Unify `B = C`, finding the values for some type variables. Then, the type `A -> D` (after unification) will be the one you mentioned.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851325/generic-type-of-map-filter for a similar example.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701189/849891) for a very close duplicate.

Comment: also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029843/how-can-i-understand/849891) is closely related.

Comment: [How to determine type of Haskell functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11638232/791604) includes some tips on solving questions like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.)` has the type `(b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))`. I intentionally added some parentheses for clarity. There are three instances of `(.)` in the expression `(.) . (.)` so having the type in three versions using different letters will be handy.

- `(.) :: (b -> c) -> ((a -> b) -> (a -> c))` – the first instance of `(.)`: `(.)`**`.`**`(.)`
- `(.) :: (e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))` – the second instance of `(.)`: **`(.)`**`. (.)`
- `(.) :: (h -> i) -> ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))` – the third instance of `(.)`: `(.) .`**`(.)`**

`(.) . (.)` is aequivalent to `((.) (.)) (.)`, it's applying `(.)` to `(.)` and then applying the result of the first application to `(.)`.

#### Application of the first instance to the second instance

Match the type of the argument (`(e -> f) -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`) to the input type of `(.)` (`b -> c`):

```
b = (e -> f)
c = ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))
```

Then substitue the type variables in the result type of `(.)` (`(a -> b) -> (a -> c)`) by the matches from the argument:

```
(.) (.) :: (a -> (e -> f)) -> (a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f)))
```

#### Application of the result of the first application to the third instance

Match the type of the argument (`(h -> i) -> ((g -> h) -> (g -> i))`) to the input type of `(.) (.)` (`a -> (e -> f)`):

```
a = (h -> i)
e = (g -> h)
f = (g -> i)
```

Then substitue the type variables in the result type of `(.) (.)` (`a -> ((d -> e) -> (d -> f))`) by the matches from the argument:

```
(.) (.) (.) :: (h -> i) -> ((d -> (g -> h)) -> (d -> (g -> i)))
```

That has the same type as what you have in the question, just with more parentheses and different letters. If I remove unnecessary parentheses, this is the result:

```
(.) (.) (.) :: (h -> i) -> (d -> g -> h) -> d -> g -> i
```

What does it do? It takes two arguments of types `d` and `g`, applies a function of type `d -> g -> h` to them, then applies a function of type `h -> i` to the result.

Answer (score 0):

The type `(.) :: (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)` means

```
    g :: a -> b
f     ::      d -> c
--------------------    d ~ b
f . g :: a ->      c
```

and hence

```
      (.) :: (b->c) -> ((a->b) -> (a->c))
(.)       ::           (   s   ->    r  ) -> (t->s) -> (t->r)
-------------------------------------------------------------
(.) . (.) :: (b->c) ->                       (t->s) -> (t->r)
          ~  (b->c) ->                    (t->a->b) ->  t->a->c
```

which makes sense, because

```
  ((.) . (.))   f                            g          x  y =
 = (.) ((.) f) g x y
 =    ((f .) . g) x y = (f .) (g x) y 
                      = (f . g x) y    = f ( g          x  y )
```

because `(.) f g x = (f .) g x = (f . g) x = f (g x)` (and also `= (. g) f x`).

`(f .)` is known as *operator section* (with the `(.)` operator). It is a convenient shortcut for writing `(.) f`.